# How to globally handle/catch exceptions in Blazor.Server C#

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, blazor, blazor-server-side

I try to find solution how catching and saving exceptions in more global way in my Blazor WASM Core Hosted app, apart from putting try catch code in all my methods in my controllers.

On UI part of my app which is Blazor WebAssembly,  I am catching errors using ErrorBoundary, is work pretty good for WebAssembly, but for exceptions which came from Blazor.Server I only get '500 (Internal Server Error)' and exact place which method triggered this error in .razor component.

I would like achieve something similar, but which will work on my controllers in Blazor Server. Exact which controller and which code line on backend cause this error.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        @Body
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent Context="Exception">
        @SaveLogs(Exception)
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *API Controllers* project you can use `Middleware` to catch the exceptions globally. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cy53ENszjWo) helped me understand a lot.

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
```

**ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs**

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // Caller will either receive 200 (OK) or one of the below;
        try
        {
            await next(context);
            // Catch, handle and log known exceptions below.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500
            // When catching general exceptions, we don't want to write them to the response.
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Internal Server Error. Please Try Again Later.");
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Message: {Environment.NewLine + ex.Message} {Environment.NewLine}Trace: {Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace ?? String.Empty}");
        }

    }
}
```

I'd would love to replace `<ErrorBoundary>` with `Middleware` in the *Blazor Server Side* project, but it doesn't seem possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very elegant way of doing this. you wanna check this [Library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext), Oyu can return from Methods Result the Result is a struct that holds your data, your exceptions that happend in the previos methods etc.

Also Mr. nick chapsas on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=a1ye9eGTB98) has a whole Video about this topic.