# How do I display an exception in an inner components OnInitializedAsync()?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my razor I have:

```
<DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Followers" CaptionPosition="CaptionPosition.Vertical" Visible="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)" ColSpanMd="12">
    <UserGrid Data="@Model.Followers" />
</DxFormLayoutItem>
```

And in `UserGrid.OnInitializedAsync()` it threw an exception. How do I catch that to tell the user something bad happened? It's async so any exception it throws is lost somewhere inside Blazor.

[I know I can catch them globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75534867/how-to-globally-handle-catch-exceptions-in-blazor-server-c-sharp). But I'd like to catch them in the context of the outer razor file. So I can tell them that initializing "this page" we hit a problem.

Comment: You can use ErrorBoundaries within any razor component not just the layout. RenderFragments are delegates. ErrorBoundaries are akin to putting a try catch around the delegate call.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this article:
https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-server/dotnet7/error-handling-101402

You likely need to wrap your UserGrid in an ErrorBoundary. However, if the exception is being thrown outside of the scope of your UserGrid then the ErrorBoundary will not catch it. See "The error handler pipeline" pipeline in that article for more details.